# Showing $a_{j+1}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{4}{a_j}+a_j)$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to show the following sequence is decreasing and bounded below.

Let $a_1>2$ for $j \ge 1$ define

$a_{j+1}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{4}{a_j}+a_j)$

I am trying to show it is decreasing

First I did the induction method

Base case $a_1=3>2.16667=a_2$

Then Induction hypothesis is let $j=k$ then $a_{k}>a_{k+1}$ then show

$a_{k+1}>a_{k+2}$

So I did

$a_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}((\frac{4}{a_k}+a_{k})>\frac{1}{2}((\frac{4}{a_{k+1}}+a_{k+1}))=a_{k+2}$

But how do I show this be true??? I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can prove that $a_j\gt 2$ for every $j$ by induction using AM-GM inequality : 
$$a_{j+1}=\frac 12\left(\frac{4}{a_j}+a_j\right)\gt \sqrt{\frac{4}{a_j}\times a_j}=2.$$

So,
$$a_j-a_{j+1}=-\frac{2}{a_j}+\frac{a_j}{2}=\frac{(a_j+2)(a_j-2)}{2a_j}\gt 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = \frac{x}{2}+\frac{2}{x}$. For any $x>0$, $f(x)\geq 2$ holds by the AM-GM inequality. On the other hand, since $f(x)-x = \frac{2}{x}-\frac{x}{2}=\frac{4-x^2}{2x}$, $a_1>2$ gives: $$ 2\leq a_{j+1}<a_{j}<a_1$$
for any $j>1$. So $\{a_j\}_{j\geq 1}$ is decreasing and bounded below, hence it is converging to some $L$.

Such $L$ has to be $\geq 2$ and fulfill $L=\frac{L}{2}+\frac{2}{L}$, from which $L=2$ follows.

Comment: I never heard of this AM-GM inequality but I will look it up.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
Newton's iteration for
$x^2 = a$
is
$x_{n+1}
=\frac12\left(x_n+\frac{a}{x_n} \right)
$.

So,
your iteration is
just Newton's iteration
for $\sqrt{4}$.

Look it up.